# Create View Issue

Tags: sql, create-view

I have data in two tables that i want to get into a view to then be able to do reporting on and having trouble as only some of the records in the first table have records in the second table.
The data is ranges for a product.
For example I have 2 options the first has 6 ranges of pricing, 3 are stored in `table A` and 3 in `table B` linked by the `ID` of the record in `table A`.  The second has only 3 ranges that are in `table A` so no record is created in `table B` for this product.
When I try to do a create view and include the details from the second table I only get the details for the first option and not the second as it is excluding this because there is no record in the second table.
How do I over come this?

```
TableP1                         TableP2         
Product_id  Unit    Range 1 Range 2 Range 3 TableP1_ID      Range 4 Range 5 Range 6 TableP1_ID
1   Person  20  18  16  1       14  12  10  1
2   Person  25  22      2
```

not sure if the above makes sense.

Comment: What did your SQL look like for the view that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not have two queries and `UNION` the results together in your `VIEW` code?

Something like:

```
CREATE myView 
AS

SELECT X,
       Y
FROM   Table1

UNION

SELECT X,
       Y
FROM   Table2;
```